# FORTRAN dynamically allocate derived types

Tags: dynamic, types, polymorphism, fortran, runtime

I am using the OOP features in FORTRAN, but I am not sure if I can dynamically allocate a derived types. It could be that IVF doesn't support it or the standard (2003) forbid of doing so.

To illustrate, I have a base class DiscPlayer and 2 derived types DVDPlayer and BDPlayer

```
type, abstract :: DiscPlayer
    private
    integer, public :: Capacity = 3
endtype DiscPlayer
```

and

```
type, extends(DiscPlayer) :: DVDPlayer
    private
    integer, public :: RemoteController
endtype DVDPlayer
```

In the main program, I want the variable type to be decided at run time.

```
program test
use ModDiscPlayer
use ModDVDPlayer
use ModBDPlayer
implicit none

class(DiscPlayer), allocatable :: P1
integer :: i
i = 1  ! will add user input
select case(i)
case(1)
    allocate(DVDPlayer::P1)
    P1%RemoteController = 1
case(2)
    allocate(BDPlayer::P1)
endselect
endprogram test
```

Then I got the wrong message: error #6460: This is not a field name that is defined in the encompassing structure. Any explanation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only access those comonents and type bound procedures of the variable, which are difened in its declared type. Here, the declared type is `DiscPlayer`, so you can directly use only `Capacity`.

If you know you have or might have some concrete dynamic type, you can use the `select type` construct to access the properties of the dynamic type.

```
case(1)
    allocate(DVDPlayer::P1)

    select type(P1)
      type is (DVDPlayer)
        P1%RemoteController = 1
    end select
case(2)
```

If the run-time comparison with the type in the `select type` branch succeeds, you can than use it in that branch as it were `type(DVDPlayer)`.

Note you can also use `class is` and `class default` in `select type`.

Comment: Yes. That make sense logically. Could you tell a little more about class is? I understand type is. What's the difference of class is and type is?

Comment: `class is (t)` section is executed if the dynamic type is `t` or any extended type of `t`.